# How to enable stylecop in vs 2022?

Tags: c#, stylecop, visual-studio-2022

How can we install style cop in vs 2022?
I have installed the style cop from the market place [StyleCop Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop), But unable to see the style cop option in the visual studio 2022.
PFA.

[image: VS 2022 Snip]

Comment: Did you check Q & A from the [same link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop). Question from Debanjan Paul might help you

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, StyleCop does not support Visual Studio 2022 yet. the author
says that:

> I do not have any immediate plans to update the extension for Visual
> Studio 2022.
>
> StyleCop "Classic" is already far behind C# language versions
> (resulting in parsing errors), and StyleCopAnalyzers has been
> available to provide similar functionality since Visual Studio 2015. I
> would suggest using StyleCopAnalyzers, if possible. By Chris Dahlberg
> 11/8/2021

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/itemsitemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop&ssr=false#qna

Answer (score 4):

The stylecop feature doesn't work with `Visual Studio 2022`.
The Compatible versions are `Visual Studio 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017, 2019`.

Comment: Please try to always add a source to statements like this (even if it is obviously correct in this case ).